# Automatically unlock tables upon control C

Tags: perl, dbi, db2-luw

I have observed that if I hit control C on a running perl DBI script that the next run of the same script will hang.

I have confirmed with ps that the script is not running after I click control C.

I am using PerlDBI and DB2.

1. How can I run a query to see outstanding locks?
2. How can I change my code so it will do a rollback and unlock the tables upon control C.
3. How can I release the locks from a perl script?

Comment: Ask a single question. Don't mix multiple questions in a single post. You can arrange to catch the control-C in your perl code and perform a rollback. But if your perl code runs stored procedures, other approaches are necessary. Depending on the size of the unit-of-work , rollback can take a long time. The only way to release locks is for the application to perform either a commit or a rollback.

Comment: Isn't there a way to set on the connection to automatically rollback on disconnect?  And then when the application disconnects upon control C it would rollback.  Then it would not rely on catching a signal and would work regardless of how the application dies (perhaps kill -9).

Comment: When Db2 notices that the client connection no longer exists, Db2-LUW will rollback any uncommitted transactions from that app. We cannot tell how your app is coded, or which middleware it may use, or versions of components etc. You gave no details. As mentioned, the time taken to perform a rollback will vary with the size of the unit(s) of work. Ask an experienced DBA locally to help if you lack the skills with Db2 to prove what is happening under the covers.  That is basic problem determination, as distinct from programming.

Answer (score 2):

[Application processes, concurrency, and recovery](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=design-application-processes-concurrency-recovery):

> The database manager releases all locks it has acquired and retained on behalf of an application process when that process ends.

If your application has really ended, then all its locks must be released (we don't take into account 2-phase commit transactions here - things are more complex in this case).
So, when you press Ctrl-C, then different things may happen - you ether don't terminate the client connection or DB2 still believes, that this connection is alive (but DB2 should detect unexpected client termination automatically and disconnect the application releasing its locks).

You may use the following methods to understand what happens with distinct database connection.
The [SYSIBMADM.MON_LOCKWAITS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=mv-mon-lockwaits-retrieve-metrics-applications-that-are-waiting-obtain-locks) view shows who is holder (`HLD_*` columns) and who is waiter (`REQ_*` columns) and what's the table (`TABSCHEMA`, `TABNAME`) is the object of this lock wait.

The [MON_GET_LOCKS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=mpf-mon-get-locks-table-function-list-all-locks-in-currently-connected-database) table function shows the locks, say, held by some application handle (session) or placed to some table. A couple examples.

If you know an application handle (XXX):

```
SELECT 
  F.TABSCHEMA, F.TABNAME, L.LOCK_OBJECT_TYPE, L.LOCK_MODE 
FROM 
  TABLE (MON_GET_LOCKS('<application_handle>XXX</application_handle>', -2)) L
, TABLE 
  (
    SELECT 
      MAX (DECODE (NAME, 'TABSCHEMA', VALUE::VARCHAR (128))) AS TABSCHEMA
    , MAX (DECODE (NAME, 'TABNAME', VALUE::VARCHAR (128)))   AS TABNAME
    FROM TABLE (MON_FORMAT_LOCK_NAME (L.LOCK_NAME))
  ) F
```

If you know the full table name: `MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE`:

```
SELECT APPLICATION_HANDLE, LOCK_OBJECT_TYPE, LOCK_MODE 
FROM TABLE (MON_GET_LOCKS('<table_schema>MY_SCHEMA</table_schema><table_name>MY_TABLE</table_name>', -2))
```

An application can be forced off the database by its application handle with the [FORCE APPLICATION command using the ADMIN_CMD procedure](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-force-application-using-admin-cmd). For example, if you see some lock wait, you may take the value (say, XXX) in `SYSIBMADM.MON_LOCKWAITS.HLD_APPLICATION_HANDLE` (the application handle holding the lock) and use it in the following call to force it off the database:

`CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('force application (XXX)')`

Comment: "The database manager releases all locks it has acquired and retained on behalf of an application process when that process ends."  Any idea how I can debug that I am not seeing this behavior?  I have checked my processes and confirmed it is truly gone after the control C.  Also no zombie processes for that user.

Comment: As I said: run your program again, get hang, check presence of lock waits in the database. If you don't see them, then the problem is outside the database, and I have no idea on how to debug it further.